# Get a vector that is rotated towards a point that is perpendicular to a normal vector

Tags: c++, math, vector

I want to calculate a vector that is perpendicular to a normal vector of a plane, and if you are looking at the plane top down you will see the resulting vector pointing towards a point.

Example Image:

[image: diagram]

### What I've tried

This is the code I've made to try to calculate the vector. It doesn't work not sure what to add to fix it.

```
int sgn(float val) {
    return (0.0f < val) - (val < 0.0f);
}

void DetermineVector(Vector3 normalVector, Vector3 hitPosition, Vector3 goalPoint) {
    float deltaX = goalPoint.X - hitPosition.X; // TO - FROM
    float deltaY = goalPoint.Y - hitPosition.Y; // TO - FROM
    float deltaZ = goalPoint.Z - hitPosition.Z; // TO - FROM

    // Determine the x, z components of the vector.
    // Basic Pythagorean Theorem
    float length = sqrt(deltaX * deltaX + deltaZ * deltaZ);

    float x = deltaX / length;
    float z = deltaZ / length;

    // Determine the y component of the vector;

    // Gets the sign of angle rotation
    float crossProductSum = -normalVector.X * deltaY + normalVector.Y * deltaX;
    int sign = sgn(crossProductSum); // Gets the sign -1, 0, and 1

    // Use trigonometry to figure out the angle of the normal vector in relation to the UP vector (0, 1, 0)
    // take that angle and subtract rotate 90 and take that resulting y vector and multiply the sign
    float angle = acos(normalVector.Y);
    float y = cos(angle - 90) * sign;

    // We have to combine the components so that the Y component is the same because its already normalized
    // But we have to normalize the x, z components based on the Y component
    return Vector3(x / (1 - y), y, z / (1 - y));
}
```

Comment: Go through the math step by step on paper. Do it slowly and clearly because you'll compare the code results against the by-hand math results later. If you find you can't get the math right, don't waste your time on code. Keep working by hand until you know exactly how to solve the problem. Assuming you've got the math down, you step through the code with the debugger that should have come with your development tools make sure the output of every line of code exactly matches your pen-and-paper calculations. If it doesn't, you've found a mistake and probably have a good idea what went wrong.

Comment: @user4581301 I'll keep that in mind for next time. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In other words you're seeking a vector from hitPosition towards the projection of goalPoint along the Y axis. You don't need trigonometry for this.

A vector (X,Y,Z) is perpendicular to the normal of the plane if it satisfies:

```
X*normalVector.X + Y*normalVector.Y + Z*normalVector.Z == 0
```

(See [dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product).)

That vector points towards the projection of goalPoint along Y axis if

```
X = deltaX
Z = deltaZ
```

Substituting and solving for Y:

```
Y = -(deltaX*normalVector.X + deltaZ*normalVector.Z)/normalVector.Y
```

You can normalize the result at the end if needed.

Putting it all together:

```
Vector3 DetermineVector(Vector3 normalVector, Vector3 hitPosition, Vector3 goalPoint) {
    float deltaX = goalPoint.X - hitPosition.X; // TO - FROM
    float deltaY = goalPoint.Y - hitPosition.Y; // TO - FROM
    float deltaZ = goalPoint.Z - hitPosition.Z; // TO - FROM

    float X = deltaX;
    float Y = -(deltaX*normalVector.X + deltaZ*normalVector.Z)/normalVector.Y;
    float Z = deltaZ;

    // optionally normalize:
    float length = sqrt(X*X + Y*Y + Z*Z);
    X /= length, Y /= length, Z /= length;

    return Vector3(X, Y, Z);
}
```

Comment: It says I shouldn't thank you in the comments, but I just have to say thank you, and that this has been extremely helpful. Thank you so much.